# Append svelte component to another component, depending on the viewport width

Tags: svelte, sapper

There are 3 components - A, B, C.
C component is in A.

If viewport width smaller then x px need to remove C component into B.

Its easy to do with vanilla js. Is it possible to do in svelte without creating two C components ?

vanilla-js-example - `<https://codepen.io/vladbelozertsev/pen/eYzoYmO?editors=1111>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't really an officially supported way / construct to do that. In Svelte, the only case where a component moves in the tree is with keyed lists:

```html
{#each items as item}
  <MyComponent key={item.id}>{item.text}</MyComponent>
{/each}
```

There's been some discussion about [portals](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4237), and even [a lib](https://github.com/romkor/svelte-portal).

Otherwise you can still implement something like this yourself, by using the DOM API to move the elements in a Svelte component yourself.

Bellow is an example that moves "a component" (really, the elements of the component -- the component itself stays in the same place in the virtual Svelte component tree) -- [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/57bd5798acbe49cf992f65928bb7943e?version=3.29.7).

`Child.svelte`

```html
<div>I am Child</div>
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import Child from './Child.svelte'
    
    let wrapper
    let left
    let right
    
    const goLeft = () => {
        left.appendChild(wrapper)
    }
    
    const goRight = () => {
        right.appendChild(wrapper)
    }
</script>

<button on:click={goLeft}>Left</button>

<button on:click={goRight}>Right</button>

<div>
    <div class="container left" bind:this={left} />
    <div class="container right" bind:this={right} />
</div>

<div bind:this={wrapper}>
    <Child />
</div>
```